# IIS 6.1 - Authentication works but NOT only with certain IP Adress (NAT ? )

Tags: windows, iis, authentication

I'm using an IIS Server and run into the following problem since ~5days without any new changes on all infra: 
Some clients didn't arrived to pass the step after authentification (login pass =>ok)  : error on aspx page, header & footer are ok, but composition of the content is not possible.
I can reproduce the bug with my phone access point , cloud access & orange pro in mauritius.

I have a stormshield v50 firwall & a windows 2008R2, all these equipment are fully up to date.

On IIS, Form authentification is enabled with http 302login/redirect & Mode : Use device profile

In wireshark I just saw only the error & after a reset tcp from client

It's weird only certain ip causing problem !!!

I have just tried to use my wifi on my phone => ok, deactivate wifi => refresh & ko "Page error, composition was not possible"

Thanks a lot for your help !

```
                <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Acces, App_Web_avnfg6h3" %>

                <%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/TopMenuPublic.ascx" TagName="TopMenuPublic"
                    TagPrefix="uc1" %>
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head id="Head1" runat="server">
                => render OK
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                => render KO
```

[wireshark bad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD4Ss.jpg)

Comment: Make sure to ask an actual question or questions in your post.  This helps to make it clear what you are trying to solve.

Comment: "In wireshark I just saw only the error & after a reset tcp from client" but we can see nothing here. If you don't intend to share some useful info, there is nothing to be discussed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm sorry for my poors data